# Fixed header table, scrollable body to occupy 100% height of resizable DIV

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position

I have a table which I effectively want to have a fixed header and allow the rows in the table to be scrolled through while the header row remains static. In addition, I want the body section of the table to take up the remaining height in the containing element that is left after the header row is rendered.

So far I have two tables, the first contains a thead, tr and multiple th, the second contains the tbody with multiple tr each with multiple td, like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
            <th>Heading 3</th>
            <th>Heading 4</th>
            <th>Heading 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div style="overflow:scroll">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /></tr>
            <tr><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've done some research and found out that setting a style up as follows on a DIV makes it scale to the height of its containing element

```
position:absolute;
height:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

The problem is that setting a position of absolute on both the table containing the header and the table containing the body sets them to render at 0, 0 within the containing element. I could specifiy a pixel value for the CSS top property but this makes it more rigid.

Is there some key CSS positioning value or combination that I'm not thinking of that could help me achieve all of this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html ?
You don't even have to split the table into two tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could specifiy a pixel value for the CSS top property but this makes it more rigid.

Yes, but this *is* what you want, isn't it?

That's really the only solution.

Comment: To be honest, my CSS skills are definitely in padawan status, so I'm really hoping someone knows of a better way than that.

Comment: But do you want the header to get bigger/smaller when the window gets bigger/smaller? From your question I'd think the answer to that would be "no". And if "no", then what is wrong with using some absolute measurement like px? I agree with you that it would be better to have some sort of alternative layout mechanism which would let you only specify this value once and have the other container fill the remaining space - but it just doesn't exist when you're trying to do this kind of thing. There are some other variations of this option, but they all require you to specify that value twice in px

Comment: You're right I don't want the header to get bigger or smaller when the window is resized but if the user increases the font size, gaps start to appear. I guess I can live with the ugliness. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @A Murray, AH! Now that's another question! You can use any measurement unit you want there... it doesn't have to be PX... you can use EM instead.